# How to pipe credentials to cryptroot-unlock for automatic LUKS unlock on boot

Tags: 20.04, ssh, encryption, luks, initramfs

My root partition is encrypted with LUKS so on every boot I get prompted for the passphrase, I've installed dropbear-initramfs so that I can SSH in and provide the passphrase headlessly with "cryptroot-unlock", but I'd like to truly automate this.

I have another device on the network that is fully encrypted so I was just going to make a service that looks for the dropbear server and, if it finds it, SSH in and provide the passphrase, I'm just having trouble passing the passphrase to cryptroot-unlock.

So far I've tried:

```
ssh <server> "cryptroot-unlock <password>"
ssh <server> "echo <password> | cryptroot-unlock"
```

Both of which respond:

```
cryptsetup: cryptsetup failed, bad password or options?
```

It's worth noting that my passphrase doesn't have any quotation marks or other special characters that need escaping.

Is anyone aware of a way to remotely decrypt a Ubuntu root partition that doesn't require manual intervention? I have no problem storing credentials in plaintext on another Ubuntu box that has LUKS enabled, heck they could even look for each others dropbear server and decrypt each other when one's rebooted.

Answer (score 4):

I think you're missing the `-n` option for echo. By default echo adds a newline character to the end, which is a common headache. Try

```
echo -n <password> | cryptroot-unlock
```

Comment: cryptroot-unlock do not accept returns as it reads with `cat > "$PASSFIFO"` so new line is not stripped

Comment: in case you are using 1password cli, it accepts -n as well. 
`op read -n op://_scripts/myhost/password | ssh myhost cryptroot-unlock`